# Unidirectional relation in Hibernate Spring Boot

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to have a unidirectional one-to-one relation in Hibernate JPA where the owner entity of the foreign key cannot reference the source entity.

For example, if I have 2 entities, A and B, and B has a foreign key constraint with A like:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
                                     `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `B` (
                                     `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                     `A_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                                     `created_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                                     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                                     UNIQUE KEY `AyIdUnique` (`A_id`),
                                     CONSTRAINT `FK_A_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`A_id`) REFERENCES `A`
)
```

Is there a way to make the entity B accessible from entity A, but the entity A not accessible from entity B?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Is this for data security?

Comment: This was for making an entity not accessible by the other one.

Comment: That I understood, but is the underlying reason for data security? Just trying to understand what motivates this need.

Answer (score 0):

A unidirectional one-to-one mapping is possible with entity B accessible from entity A, but not the other way around. Use the @OneToOne annotation on the related entity field in class A, and the @JoinColumn to the column in table A that maps to the primary key in table B e.g:

e.g:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    //... 
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private B b;
    // ... getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    //...
    // no reference to A here
    //
}
```

However to enter data into entity A or B without violating constraints, you should create an instance of entity B. Then, create an instance of entity A, and then set the reference to the instance of B. After that, persist the instance of entity A.
(i.e. because entity A is the owner of the relationship, and it contains the foreign key to entity B) e.g:

```
// Instantiate EntityManager
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPersistenceUnit");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

em.getTransaction().begin();

// Create an instance of B
B b = new B();
// Set properties of b as needed
b.setCreatedBy("user1");
em.persist(b);

// Create an instance of A and set the reference to b
A a = new A();
a.setB(b);
// Set other properties of a as needed
em.persist(a);

em.getTransaction().commit();

em.close();
emf.close();
```

Comment: My question was about having it the other way around.

Comment: So swap a for b...